# jScrollPane not showing in DIV

Tags: jquery, html, web, jscrollpane

Firstly, I've searched for a while and couldn't find an answer that has worked for me.

I'm developing a website for a client. I am using jScrollPane jQuery plugin but it's not showing. I was at first concerned that maybe some other jQuery Plugins were effecting it, but when I apply the .scroll-pane class to something it stretches the height of the div to show all the content without scrollbars. I don't know, it may still have something to do with it, I can't tell. I can't show the site as I sign non-disclosure agreements with all my clients, but I can show the relevant code.

These are the script links in my header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/jScrollPane.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/supersized.3.1.3.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jScrollPane.js"></script>
```

This is the relevant HTML with the nested DIVs:

```
<!--INFO TAB-->

<div id="infocontainer"> 
    <div id="infobox"> 
    </div>
    <div id="infomenu"> 
    </div>
    <div id="inforule"> 
    </div>
    <div id="infocontent" class="scroll-pane">
        TEXTTEXTT EXTTEXTTEXTTEXT TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEX TTEXTTEXTT EXTTEXTTEXTT EXTTEXT TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTT EXTTEXTT EXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEX TTEXTTEXTTEX TTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTE XTTE XTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEX TTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script that calls the function just before the end of the body:

```
<script>
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
</script>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#infocontainer {

    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:350px;
    height:385px;
    width:625px;
    z-index:1;

}

#infobox {
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;

}

#infomenu {

    padding-top:44px;
    padding-left:49px;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:1;

}

#inforule {

    margin-left:239px;
    margin-top:-175px;
    z-index:5;

}

#infocontent {

    line-height:18px;
    margin-left:290px;
    margin-top:-287px;
    height:284px;
    overflow:auto;
    width:270px;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:1;

}
```

The DIVs opacity is initially 0 and then some custom javascript I wrote brings them to 100% when the page loads. I am also using the Supersize jQuery that sets up full screen fit background images.

I have no idea why it's no working, I've tried turning all other javascript and jQuery use off with only the jScrollPane on and it still does't work any better or worse. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console/firebug?

Comment: @juliep The only thing that comes up as red in the console is the following for the jScrollPane.js

currentOffset is Null

currentOffset.top -= dragPosition;

Comment: for kicks, try to revert your jquery to a previous version, like 1.5.2. check this out: http://code.google.com/p/jscrollpane/issues/detail?id=207#c2

Comment: @juliep !!!!!!!!!!!! Oh my god I love you :P I can see the scrollbar, it's not aligned right, but I have a starting point. I'll see how new I can make jQuery before it stuffs up again. Thank you so much, you should have posted as an answer so I can rate it! :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for kicks, try to revert your jquery to a previous version, like 1.5.2. check this out: code.google.com/p/jscrollpane/issues/detail?id=207#c2 – julie p

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the content of the Div inside the

tag like

```
<p>
TEXTTEXTT EXTTEXTTEXTTEXT TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEX TTEXTTEXTT EXTTEXTTEXTT EXTTEXT TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTT EXTTEXTT EXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEX TTEXTTEXTTEX TTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTE XTTE XTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEX TTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything. :/